# Sql complex group by query (oracle jpa)

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

```
id     let      num    dir    ctry
----------------------------------
0       A       10      W      US   <- first row of route (A-W)
1       A       20      W      CA
2       A       30      W      MX
3       B       25      E      US
4       B       30      E      CA
5       B       20      E      CA   <- first row of route (B-E)
```

I have a table which is composed of segments (1 row = 1 segment) and routes (multiple segments).

A route is composed of segments having the same "let" and "dir" combination.  So the first 3 rows is one route, and the last 3 rows is another.

The first segment in the route is the row with the smallest `num`.

- So, row `id = 0` is the first segment in route 1,
- and the last row `id = 5` is the first segment in route 2.

I want to return the rows that make up a route based on the 1st segment of that route equaling a given country.

If I filtered on a "ctry" of CA the result would be the following:

```
id     let    num     dir   ctry
--------------------------------
3       B      25      E     US
4       B      30      E     CA
5       B      20      E     CA
```

Comment: what have you try? do you need a sql or some orm code?

Comment: You need to explain what `If I filtered on a "ctry" of CA` means. I guess was route has any `CA`

Comment: I just make an edit. To make clear what is the first row, Is that ok?

Comment: yes, you are correct with the edits.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM YourTable 
 WHERE (let, dir) IN (SELECT distinct let, dir
                      FROM YourTable Y
                      WHERE Y.ctry = 'CA')
```

OR

```
 SELECT L.*
 FROM YourTable L
 JOIN (SELECT distinct let, dir
       FROM YourTable Y
       WHERE Y.ctry = 'CA') R
   ON L.let = R.let
  AND L.dir = R.dir
```

Based on your comment <kbd>[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96fc12/30)</kbd>

```
SELECT R.*
FROM 
     (SELECT let, dir, min(num) as minnum
      FROM Routes t
      GROUP BY let, dir
     )  minT
JOIN  (SELECT t.*
       FROM Routes t      
      )  firstrow
   ON minT.let = firstrow.let
  AND minT.dir = firstrow.dir
  AND minT.minnum = firstrow.num
JOIN  Routes R
   ON firstRow.let = R.let
  AND firstRow.dir = R.dir
  AND firstRow.Ctry = 'CA';
```

Comment: I'm using a jpa version that doesn't support multiple-column in clauses, but the second query posted works.     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99590/17    I throw in a ORDER BY but it doesn't appear to order the num column correctly.

Comment: Yes,I  tought in give you the more generic version too just in case. Glad that work for you.

Comment: `ORDER BY L.id,L.let,L.num`  after you order `ID` the other fields doesnt matter.

Comment: I just realized the query you posted compares every segment in every route against the "ctry" column.  I only want the first segment in each route to be compared.

Comment: Can you explain further? Because your result show first segment is `US`

Comment: I've updated the 2nd row in the table to have "CA" as the value for "ctry".  This second row corresponds to the 2nd segment in route 1, which should not be compared against the "ctry" column in order to determine if the route should be returned. Changing this causes every row to be returned.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96fc1/1

Comment: Yes, because you want segment with `CA`. Maybe you need explain further. Please read [**Need an Answer? Actually, No ... You Need a Question**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

Comment: Please re-read my original post, I clearly say to "return the rows that make up a route based on the 1st segment of that route equaling a given country."

Comment: ok, but I read your post, and if you select `CA` how your result show any data ? Your sample doesnt have any first row with `CA` both first rows are `US`

Comment: Your query you provided compares all the segments (all rows in the table) against the provided "ctry", if there are any matches then the route is returned.  I only want the first segment of the route (this is defined as the row with the smallest "num" value in the route).  understand?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can do this using analytics function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(country) keep (dense_rank first order by num) over (partition by let, dir) as first_country
      from t
     ) t
where first_country = 'CA';
```

JPA is more limited.  This might work:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select let, dir, min(num) as minnum
      from t
      group by let, dir
     ) ld 
     on t.let = ld.let and t.dir = ld.dir join
     t tt
     on tt.let = ld.let and tt.dir = ld.dir and tt.num = ld.minnum
where tt.country = 'CA';
```

Comment: Your query is missing an `on` clause . . . which I see is also missing in my answer (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96fc1/16).

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae58a/1

By using your guys direction I came up with a good solution that is readable.  Thanks juan and gordon.

```
SELECT Routes.* FROM Routes
JOIN (SELECT let,dir,min(num) as minnum
      FROM Routes
      GROUP BY let, dir
      ) ld JOIN Routes tt
ON tt.let = ld.let AND tt.dir = ld.dir AND tt.num = ld.minnum 
AND Routes.let = ld.let AND Routes.dir = ld.dir
WHERE tt.ctry = 'CA';
```

Comment: Is there a way to write the above without the JOIN keyword, just using old style joins?